# .NET winform - Checkbox nullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

When im trying to set checkbox.checked, i got null refedence exception. I dont know why, it looks like that checkbox isnt initialized.

There is my code

```
public UpdateProduct(DataGridViewRow row,Form1 form)
{
    this.row = row;
    this.form = form;
    product = row.DataBoundItem as object;
    visibilityCheckBox.Checked = true;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Exception is firing in line `visibilityCheckBox.Checked = true;`

Please can anybody help me with this issue ? Thanks much !

Comment: if you are passing a form and doing this it won't be possible.. you will need invokes

Comment: This sounds weird. Do you create it dynamically?

Comment: @stakx: I closed first too as duplicate of that one, but I guess OP knows what a NRE is. I guess there is just a misunderstanding of how the generated WF code initializes the controls.

Comment: Voted to close since `NullReferenceException`s are really always the same thing, and the linked answer shows how to fix them. It may *look like* `visibilityCheckBox` has been initialized, but if you get that exception, then it *wasn't* initialized (or it was reset to `null`). Add a breakpoint on all lines where that field is initialized/set and see if your code ever stops there. Then figure out why it doesn't stop there.

Comment: i forgot that InitializeComponent() must be called first ! Stupid mistake ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't call `InitializeComponent` before, and since you are trying to set it before the call to `InitializeComponent`, `visibilityCheckBox` will be `null`.

Call `InitializeComponent` first or write another method that does only update the created UI elements.

Comment: im so dumb ! didnt noticed that. Thanks much ! :)